# Container of pointers with aggregate initialization

Tags: c++

Name of the question is kind of ambiguous, but I don't know how it is called.
I can create a container of objects with manual input like

```
std::vector<myobj> vec = 
{ 
{ /*All fields here*/ }, ... {/*Fields here*/}
};
```

But what about pointers? What is a proper syntax to use new in order to create a vector of pointers?

Regarding answers that suggest to explicitly create distinct new objects, that was exactly the thing I wanted to avoid.

I came up with:

```
std::vector<myobj*> vec = 
{ (new myobj{ /*fields*/ }) };

 ....

for (auto& c : vec) 
    delete c;
vec.clear();
```

I don't see why it might be wrong, by still I doubt.

Comment: It should be "aggregate initialization": https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `new` directly in your list initialization.

```
std::vector<myobj*> vec = {new MyObj(), new MyObj()}
```

You still have to manage to `delete` the pointers at the end.

Answer (score 3):

This is called aggregate initialization and to initialize a vector of pointers, just define your vector type as a pointer and initialize them like for any other type:

```
MyObjc myObj1* = new MyObj();
MyObjc myObj2* = new MyObj();

std::vector<MyObj*> vec = { myObj1, myObj2 };
```

Remember to delete those pointers properly after creating them or consider using something like `std:unique_ptr` instead.

Refs:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: But to be completely correct, you should add cleanup for this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Replace each `{/* All fields here */}` by a pointer.

```
myobj o1, o2;
std::vector<myobj*> vec = {
  &o1, &o2
};
```

The usual caveats about pointers and object lifetime apply. Try not to let them dangle.